# Is there any api to invite a new user to slack workspace (unpaid)?

Tags: google-apps-script, slack, slack-api

I want to write a scirpt (Google Apps Script) to add/invite new user (not in slack) to the slack workspace (which is unpaid). Is there any api to **invite a non-slack user (using email)** (or) **to add an user(who is already in slack) to the unpaid workspace**
I have my admin's person token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only accomplish this using Slack's Admin API, unfortunately, that API is only available to Enterprise customers.

Comment: So we could only add/ invite the user using their GUI app & not the api in the free version?

Comment: Correct, you can only invite a new user to a free Workspace via the UI using the person's email or using an invitation link. Those options are outlined here: https://slack.com/intl/en-ca/help/articles/201330256-Invite-new-members-to-your-workspace